# SockJS multiple sockets

Tags: spring, sockjs

I have spring + SockJS application, that is using ActiveMQ as message broker.

Can I have two sockets on same JSP page, one with sending and receiving ,and the other one only for receiving stomp messages(with lot of traffic).Is it  guaranteed taht all messages will be delivered and received from both of sockets?

Regards,
Marko

Answer (score 0):

While connected, yes. If you lose the connection at any point, you will lose everything between disconnecting and reconnecting. [A related discussion of this issue](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sockjs/drG5B4PhmeE) comes to this conclusion.

Keep in mind that SockJS may result in different connections types on different clients, such as websocket, xhr, xdr, etc. On any connection SockJS will still use TCP and will still guarantee in-order delivery. However, non-websocket connections can take longer to trigger the close event, so you'll have longer black-out periods at the client. Almost any service needs to worry about this, because SockJS will sometimes fail to connect a websocket and "downgrade" to xhr (in my experience under high instantaneous load).

A good pattern is to add a reconnect in the close event handler.  The close even is fired even when a connection fails to be established, which means you'll want a back-off latency on the reconnect to prevent a self-inflicted [DDoS](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/D/DDoS_attack.html) on your server. Separately, I add sequential packet numbers, and treat any client that detects a missing packet as a late joiner. (See this [related ZMQ discussion on late joiners](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Recovery-and-Late-Joiners).) Your application needs may vary.